# can a projection vector be $0,0,0$?

Tags: vectors

if i have a vector $\vec a = (i,j,k) $ projected into vector $\vec d = i_2,j_2,k_2$
and both of them is perpendicular, will the projection vector be 0,0,0 ?
if yes, what identity to prove this?

lets say the projection vector is $\vec x$
then
$\vec x = \frac{|\vec x|}{|\vec d|}\vec d$  (but doesn't show that perpendicular thing make it zero)

also
$|\vec x| = \cos \theta . |\vec a|$ (the $\theta$ here is between $\vec a$ and $\vec x$ whats perpendicular is $\vec a$ and $\vec d$

Comment: Since they are perpendicular, $\cos\theta=\cos\frac{\pi}{2}=0$.

Comment: $\vec x=\dfrac{\vec a\cdot \vec d}{\vec d \cdot \vec d}\vec d=\vec 0$

Comment: $\vec x = \vec d$ why is it 0? $\vec d \neq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the projection can be zero and studying when it's zero gives us a lot of information about the linear transformation. The zero vectors is perpendicular to all other vectors and in fact you can project every vector onto it. Typically if a vector $(x,y,z)$ is projected into the zero vector we say it's part of the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(linear_algebra)) or nullspace of the linear transformation. All the vectors that are projected onto the zero vector form their own vector space.

To prove this we first use the notation $x^Ty$ to represent the dot product of $x \cdot y$. For two vectors to be orthogonal means that $x^Ty=0$. Now for some non-zero vector $d$ we set $u = d /|d|$ to be the unit vector in the direction of $d$. I now claim that the matrix $P=uu^T$ will be the orthogonal projection onto the span of $d$.

First, we see that for any $x$ that $Px = (uu^T)x=u(u^Tx)$ and since $u^Tx$ is a scalar the vector $Px$ is some scalar multiple of $d$, ie in the span of $d$. For this to be the orthogonal projection we need to show that $Px$ is orthogonal to $x-Px$ since $x-Px + Px = x$. This requires two other small details, first that $P^2=(uu^T)(uu^T) = u(u^Tu)u^T=uu^T=P$ so that we have $P^2=P$ and we need $P^T=(uu^T)^T=(u^T)^Tu^T= uu^T=P$, that is $P$ is symmetric. Finally we take the dot product of these vectors gives us $$(Px)^T(x-Px) = x^TP^T(x-Px)=x^TP^Tx-x^TP^TPx=x^TPx-x^TP^2x=x^TPx-x^TPx=0$$

and so we conclude that they are orthogonal.